# Django submit form without page refresh

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, forms

I'm using **Django-Angular** and trying to **post a form** and obtain data in back-end..I'm able to achieve this but found that the **page is reloading** while saving the form. How can we achieve the same without page render?

forms.py

```
def home(request):
    if 'application/json' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']:
        print 'hi'
        print request.body

    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

home.html

```
<form name="indexForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>File Path</label>
        <input type="text" name="path" class="form-control" ng-model="file.path">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>File Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="file_name" class="form-control" ng-model="file.file_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>ext</label>
        <input type="text" name="ext" class="form-control" ng-model="file.ext">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

script

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    console.log('from submit')
    $http({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
        data: $scope.file,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': $cookies['csrftoken']}
    })
    }
```

Please let me know code above is **correct way of posting data**? How can we **post data** from angular to backend(django) **without page refresh**

Thanks in advance...Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your home request you should not render the page again, but rather return a string or some JSON to the client. If you are using a newish version of django you can do something like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def home(request):
if 'application/json' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']:
    print 'hi'
    print request.body
    return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})

return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Comment: thanks for reply...but the html page reload after form submit....How should i avoid page refresh after submit form

Comment: If this condition is met in your handler code:

if 'application/json' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']:

The page shouldn't refresh. As log as you submit the form using ajax on the angular side. Which it looks like you are doing.

Comment: I'm getting........ POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 403 (Forbidden) when using json response.........what could be issue?

Comment: Is the code you posted the actual code for your app?  If not post a question with the actual code.

Comment: This is my full code........... Im learning few things so created test app...Will adding Rest framework(DRF) will solve the issue?

Comment: is there any additional info that comes back with the 403? I'm thinking you are doing something wrong with your CSRFToken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108345/discussion-between-robert-moskal-and-coeus).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `type="submit` with `type="button"`. Then you can just call any method in the backend with `ng-click="ctrl.foo()"`

At least that is what I have been doing so far. Looking at the docs however indicates that is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Like I added according to the docs it's alright. However I remember reading something that angular has problems preventing the browser from submitting the form unless it manages to intercept the call.